# varImp() error : trying to get slot "responses" from an object (class "glm") that is not an S4 object

Tags: r

I am trying to get the important variables from a logit function applied on a dataset in R.

In this process - the varImp() function is giving the below error : " trying to get slot "responses" from an object (class "glm") that is not an S4 object "

Code Snippet :

> logit.1 <- glm(Default ~ . , final.data.1, family = binomial, maxit = 100)

Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

> varImp(logit.1)

Error in varImp(logit.1) : 
  trying to get slot "responses" from an object (class "glm") that is not an S4 object

Need help on getting this error resolved

Thanks

Comment: Please show a  small reproducible example

Comment: perhaps you have overwritten the `varImp` function: try restating R without loading data or `caret::varImp(logit.1)` etc.